# Writing a server in C# .NET to handle custom requests/response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I need to write a 'server' in c# (.Net 2.0) which would process requests in a specific format and produce a corresponding response in a pre-defined format.

request: (userid);(*userpwd*);+ 
response: (user_purchase1);(user_purchase2);(user_purchase3);+

As, I understand this correctly, the server is a standalone module in itself. It should be able to serve to both a website application and a windows application.

I understand the client/server model receives a httprequest and yields an output accordingly, but how can I handle a request in this custom format ?

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use Web Service hosted at a server.It can be used in .Net 2.0 and serves all the functionality , you mentioned.

Comment: I thought of it, but sending stuff in a custom message request and response is really throwing me off. I am not sure how I would do that using web services ?

Comment: I have a question about using web services. Is it possible to return the response of a web service call with something else other than XML ?
 
In this case I'd like to send the custom response message

Answer (score 1):

How about hosting a WCF service as a Windows service? See MSDN, [How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx).
OR you could just create a simple HttpHandler. Both your website and Windows app should be able to access that just as well as a "custom" server (service?).

Comment: I'm a noob to this, so I am not equipped to make an informed choice one over another. HOwever, when I read about WCF services, they seem to be a .NET 4 feature. I am tied down by being forced to use .NET 2.0 only.

Comment: Start out with an HttpHandler, they're simple and fast, and really not any different than implementing an .aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

You want to take a look at using [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) or [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx).  You can set your server app to listen on any port and handle the requests sent to that port in any custom way you'd like.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what is being asked, although it might be.